# Windows 7 - Installing anything causes HDD to become full, then slowly empty in a loop, causing the computer to lag horridly

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I have been having this problem with my pc. If I try to install anything, like DirectX or something that just needs to use an installer, my HDD will just randomly start to fill its full 3 TB and then slowly deplete back down to the normal size of what I had downloaded, sometimes doing it in a loop until the install finishes.

I have did everything with chkdisk, seatools disk check and more, all say that there is no problem with the drive itself. I have changed out the SATA cable and the problem still happens to me.

I can't find anything else about this problem, is it because of my bios settings or something along those lines, or is it actually a bad drive and checking the disk itself won't show anything.

I'm running on a clean install of Windows 7 64-Bit Ultimate, Here are my specs:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Ram: 8 GB
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640
HDD: Seagate Desktop HDD ST3000DM001 3TB
```

If anyone can help me with this problem please, as this is just getting annoying for me. I can still use my pc and do other things, but installing anything is just a pain at this point.

#### Normal during install:

[image: Normal]

#### Not Normal:

1. Full hard drive

   [image: Full hard drive]
2. Resource Monitor

   [image: Resource Monitor]
3. Resource Monitor Again

   [image: Resource Monitor Again]
4. CPU Kernel Time (In Red) Goes nuts

   [image: CPU Kernel Time (In Red) Goes nuts]
5. Resource Monitor (Write)

   [image: Resource Monitor (Write)]

#### Hypothesis:

Every time this happens, the kernel CPU % starts to exactly match the normal CPU usage, and the problem won't end until the kernel CPU usage decides to go down.

Comment: Open Resource Monitor and check what Windows reports under disk activity (sorted on Total (B/sec) while you install something. Take a screenshot like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/azK7M.jpg and it to your post.

Comment: Thank you for whoever edited the post to look better

Comment: Adding to @HoD's comment, sort the view by **Write (B/sec)** and also pay attention to the path of the files being modified. You could also run a GUI disk space display tool during the install...more than likely all this data is confined to a single folder structure that will stick out like a sore thumb. Wild guess here, but perhaps the installs depend on some other framework that is trying to perform a jit assembly and is stuck in loop that's generating lots of temp files.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I have added the images for write

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something preallocates all space when you attempt an installation.

You should:

- Run a SFC /scannow (from command prompt) to check windows files integrity
- Update windows installer package and/or try Windows Installer Cleanup Utility
- Clean your junk files from all Windows known locations.

Comment: I have tried this out, now it is time to test to see if it fixed up anything

Comment: None of this helped. Still getting the same problem

Comment: Run a disk check and also clean C:\Windows\Installer location if you didn't already.

Comment: An install pre-allocating over a TB of storage? That's not right...Why would the applications the OP is installing do that?

Comment: Because it's Windows.